# R data reshape using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have this data:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(
  type = c("Animals", "Animals", "People", "People"),
  type_group = c("Dogs", "Cats", "John", "Jane"),
  analysis1 = c(32.7, 67.5, 34.6, 56.5),
  analysis2 = c(23.7, 89.4, 45.8, 98.6),
  analysis3 = c(45.7, 45.7, 23.6, 23.6),
  analysis4 = c(14.4, 45.4, 98.0, 12.2))
```

I would like to add some new rows to the data so that it looks like this:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  type = c("Animals", "Animals", "Animals diff", "People", "People", "People diff"),
  type_group = c("Dogs", "Cats", "Dogs and cats" ,"John", "Jane", "John and Jane"),
  analysis1 = c(32.7, 67.5, 34.8, 34.6, 56.5, 21.9),
  analysis2 = c(23.7, 89.4, 65.7, 45.8, 98.6, 52.8),
  analysis3 = c(45.7, 45.7, 0.0,  23.6, 23.6, 0.0),
  analysis4 = c(14.4, 45.4, 31.0, 98.0, 12.2, 85.8))
```

The new rows are titled 'Animals diff', which is the cats figures minus the dogs figure. Similarly there is a new row call 'People diff' which is the Jane figures minus the john figures.

I know the simple way to do this would be to use `dplyr` and add the new rows as variables and make the data wider rather than longer. However that format won't work for what I want to do with the data. It specifically needs to be in this longer format as displayed in df2.

What I thought I could to is create the variables using `mutate` in `dplyr` to make the data wider, and then use `reshape` to make the data long but after playing around I can't think how to do that. Any ideas on how I can get to df2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A rbind couldn't do the trick?

```
> rbind(df1,c("People",'Me',1,2,3,4))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  type    type_group analysis1 analysis2 analysis3 analysis4
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Animals Dogs       32.7      23.7      45.7      14.4     
2 Animals Cats       67.5      89.4      45.7      45.4     
3 People  John       34.6      45.8      23.6      98       
4 People  Jane       56.5      98.6      23.6      12.2     
5 People  Me         1         2         3         4
```

Do that for every new row or create the tibble with the new rows you need to add and bind both tibbles in the same way.

```
> rbind(df1,df2)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   type         type_group    analysis1 analysis2 analysis3 analysis4
   <chr>        <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Animals      Dogs               32.7      23.7      45.7      14.4
 2 Animals      Cats               67.5      89.4      45.7      45.4
 3 People       John               34.6      45.8      23.6      98  
 4 People       Jane               56.5      98.6      23.6      12.2
 5 Animals      Dogs               32.7      23.7      45.7      14.4
 6 Animals      Cats               67.5      89.4      45.7      45.4
 7 Animals diff Dogs and cats      34.8      65.7       0        31  
 8 People       John               34.6      45.8      23.6      98  
 9 People       Jane               56.5      98.6      23.6      12.2
10 People diff  John and Jane      21.9      52.8       0        85.8
```

Comment: Hi, Yeah that makes a lot of sense actually. Could you share your code for the second chunk (re how you develop df2?). I understand the methodology but not sure how to do the calculations. Thanks

Comment: Actually I think I understand this better. Did you hack the figures in the rows? I need the code to automatically calculate the differences rather than me manually adding them (if that's what you did)

Comment: hi, df1 and df2 are the same as yours. Just to show you could rbind them without changing the column type.

Answer (score 0):

Think I managed to answer this using the `rbind` suggestion.

```
rbind(df1,c("People diff","John and Jane", 
        df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
        df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
        df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
        df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Jane'])) -> jj

rbind(df1,c("Animals diff","Dogs and cats", 
        df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 
'Dogs'],
        df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 
'Dogs'],
        df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 
'Dogs'],
        df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 
'Dogs'])) -> c_d

rbind(jj, c_d)


# A tibble: 10 x 6
  type         type_group    analysis1 analysis2 analysis3 analysis4
<chr>        <chr>         <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Animals      Dogs          32.7      23.7      45.7      14.4     
2 Animals      Cats          67.5      89.4      45.7      45.4     
3 People       John          34.6      45.8      23.6      98       
4 People       Jane          56.5      98.6      23.6      12.2     
5 People diff  John and Jane -21.9     -52.8     0         85.8     
6 Animals      Dogs          32.7      23.7      45.7      14.4     
7 Animals      Cats          67.5      89.4      45.7      45.4     
8 People       John          34.6      45.8      23.6      98       
9 People       Jane          56.5      98.6      23.6      12.2     
10 Animals diff Dogs and cats 34.8      65.7      0         31
```